# Implementing Swipe Animation like Pivot Page in PhoneApplicationPage windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, storyboard, expression-blend

I am having a lot of Items(Say 100), I want the user to swipe right and left to see the detailed description of Items.

I thought of using a Pivot Control, but that is causing performance problem because of too many items.

Now, In order to make it lightweight, I want to implement the scenario in a Single page and change the DataContext when the user swipes. I know that swipe gestures can be detected from the toolkit project. Now, I want to animate my grid, when swipe gestures happening exactly like Pivot Page or a Normal Scroll behaviour. I searched a bit, and found that it can be done by creating StoryBoard animation but I am less experienced in that. Any code sample will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You could still go for the pivot control! Only thing to do is adding / removing the items dynamically. So only load first next and first previous. When the index of the pivot changes, reload.

Comment: My pivot also has Incremental Loading behaviour, so at the end of the List I have to fetch and add new items and when I use Pivot, its looping nature causes problems in fetching sequence. And post some minimum implementation of what you explained in your comment. Thanks

Comment: I was not talking about adding items to your lists, but adding/removing 'pivots' to the Pivot Control. So that you only have 3 Pivot items at maximum inside your pivot control.

Comment: Can you post a sample implementation of it ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can make archive page and when the user select the item jump to the pivot with selected index

Comment: There are too many items with complex object, that creates delay in Navigation to the page (say 10 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Small possible code sample.

In your page code behand, initialize a Dictionary ( where int is the position and pivotitem the pivot )
Load it up with 3 pivots at start
Than if your Pivot control is called AllPivots, do AllPivots.Items.Add(pivotItem) for each pivot inside the dictionary.

Next thing to do is detect how the user is changing the pivots, so if the selectedindex changes of AllPivots, see if the user advances, if so, add the next pivot into the dictionary and also to the AllPivots.Items and remove the first pivot with AllPivots.Items.Remove.

Each time the user goes back or forward look up the next or previous pivot in the dictionay and perform the correct actions or create new pivots on the fly.

Like I said a dirty hack, but maybe worth a try